# User biographical information erased on login

Tags: user-meta, bug

When any user logs into my Wordpress install, it deletes their biographical information for some reason.

I know this by watching the value of a query similar to

```
select*from wp_usermeta where meta_key='description' and user_id=19
```

...and sure enough, the meta description disappears after login.

I'll be turning plugins on and off and experimenting in a dev environment shortly, but in the meantime can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

The Active Directory Integration plugin causes this. I've posted a bug report and will perhaps contribute a fix.